# Placing markers from mongo do to google map using dburles:google-maps

Tags: google-maps, meteor

This Meteor code needs to place 10 markers on google map, the markers need to  match the first 10 locations in the address property of a mongo collection document.
The addresses are in the formate "55 abc St. Sydney 2000"
I am not sure how to do it. Any suggestions? thx

```
Template.gmap.helpers({
  mapOptions: function () {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
        zoom: 13
      };
    }
  }
});
Template.gmap.onRendered(function () {
  GoogleMaps.load();
});
Template.gmap.onCreated(function () {
  GoogleMaps.ready('map', function (map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.options.center,
      map: map.instance
    });
    //Access a map instance any time by using the maps object.
    //  GoogleMaps.maps.exampleMap.instance
  });
});
```

```html
<template name="gmap">
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout how it worked for this guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796943/meteor-autorun-wont-make-my-code-dynamic?noredirect=1#comment72755821_42796943) with this [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmaps) module.

Here's the documentation for how you can [add markers](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/markers.html), as well as use [geocoding](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geocoding.html) to turn addresses into longitude and latitude.